# Ajax request delay 1 second

Tags: ajax, performance, response

This time my problem is delay between ajax request, and  php file response.I have checked it out with google chrome statistics, and it shows almost always exact 1 second wait time every time function loops and sends ajax GET request.This makes my script pretty much unusable cause it slows so much, that browser get's unresponsive till it executes full loop.

I tried to remove all MYSQL queries, so exclude MYSQL as the problem, and delay still existed.Im pretty much sure it's not MYSQL taking so long to execute.

Does anyone have any idea what may be this delay caused on.Maybe it's some settings on my PC, or something with AJAX?

Thank You

---

[image: maybe this will help]

Maybe this will explain better.

Comment: AJAX from where? with what?

Comment: var ajaxRequest = "long response time" + " any idea what is causing it" + "?"; alert(ajaxRequest); :)

Comment: show code, we cannot fix this with a picture - edit your question to include the actual code you are using and any relevent markup

Answer (score 0):

YES!I've figured it out.Apearantly my MYSQL connection have taken it's time, the reason was that i've used localhost to initiate connection instead 127.0.0.1.Now It's much MUCH faster! :D .No reason blaming AJAX, simple 127.0.0.1 did the trick.